# Path issues in django

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-views, django-urls

I am facing a path issue where after clicking "Login" button which is in `/login/` path it looks out for `/login/login/` , whereas after clicking the "Login" button I want to return it to my root path.

I am attaching the snippets of the code and the snaps, please if somebody comes out with a solution do help.

"signup.html file"

```
<form action="signup/" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input class="text" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="">
                    <input class="text email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
                    <input class="text" type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Password" required="">
                    <input class="text w3lpass" type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="">
                    <input class="text" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" required="">
                    <!-- <div class="wthree-text">
                        <label class="anim">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" required="">
                            <span>I Agree To The Terms & Conditions</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="clear"> </div>
                    </div> -->
                    <input type="submit" value="SIGNUP">
                </form>
```

"login.html file"

```
<form action="login/" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input class="text" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="">
                    <input class="text" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
        

                    <input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
</form>
```

"urls.py file"

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('signup/',views.signup,name='signup'),
    path('login/',views.login,name='login'),

]
```

"views.py file"

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import SignUp
from django.contrib.auth.models import auth

# Create your views here.

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username= request.POST['username']
        password= request.POST['password']

        user = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return redirect('')
    else:

        return render(request,'login.html')

def signup(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username= request.POST['username']
        email= request.POST['email']
        password1= request.POST['password1']
        password2= request.POST['password2']
        address= request.POST['address']
        html = "<html><body>Confirm Password and Password should be same </body></html>"
        html1= "<html><body>User Already present </body></html>"

        if password1 != password2:
            return HttpResponse(html)
        else:
            for instance in SignUp.objects.all():
                if (instance.username == username) or (instance.email==email):
                    return HttpResponse(html1)
            signup=SignUp(username=username,email=email,password=password1,address=address)
            signup.save()

            return redirect('login')

    else:

        return render(request,'signup.html')
```

The errors I am getting :

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGXxE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are using relative paths in the forms `action` field. Instead of `action="login/"` use `action="/login/"`.

Without this, the browser appends the action path to the current pages path. So if you are at `/login`, and the login form submits, the browser sends it to `/login/login/`.

Alternatively, since the GET and POST page use the same path, you could omit the action field altogether. The browser will automatically submit the request to the current path.

Comment: This time it didn't go for /login/login/ but gave an error : "ValueError at /login/ The view signup.views.login didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. "

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**login.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input class="text" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="">
                        <input class="text" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
            
    
                        <input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
    </form>
```

**signup.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'signup' %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input class="text" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="">
                    <input class="text email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
                    <input class="text" type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Password" required="">
                    <input class="text w3lpass" type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="">
                    <input class="text" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" required="">
                    <!-- <div class="wthree-text">
                        <label class="anim">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" required="">
                            <span>I Agree To The Terms & Conditions</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="clear"> </div>
                    </div> -->
                    <input type="submit" value="SIGNUP">
                </form>
```

Comment: This time it didn't go for /login/login/ but gave an error :  "ValueError at /login/
The view signup.views.login didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. "

Comment: do you written any app_name before urlpatters in your urls.py? like this **app_name = 'signup'**

Comment: `from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('signup/',views.signup,name='signup'),
    path('login/',views.login,name='login'),

]`          my url.py file

Comment: What is your app name?

Comment: "signup" is my app name and the above urls.py is inside the signup app

Comment: @SaptarsheeSarkar, you have to return `redirect` or `HttpResponse` also if **user** is `None`

Comment: @SaptarsheeSarkar, in your **login** view: `if user is not None: ... else return render(request,'login.html')`

Answer (score 0):

**In start it is good idea to make all path in html file dynamic using Reverse resolution of URLs**

"urls.py file"

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('signup/',views.signup,name='signup'),
    path('login/',views.login,name='login'),

]
```

signup.html

```
<form action="{% url 'signup' %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
....
</form>
```

[Doc..Django Reverse resolution of URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls)